# Error libtool: can't locate file for: -lwebp when I compile a cocos2dx project

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation, cocos2d-x

I am getting an error libtool: `can't locate file for: -lwebp` when I compile a cocos2dx project
I have tried adding this library from `$(SRCROOT)/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/ios/libraries`
Also added path in Header search path but the error is not resolved

Full error trace:

> /Applications/Xcode
>   2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool:
>   can't locate file for: -lwebp /Applications/Xcode
>   2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool:
>   file: -lwebp is not an object file (not allowed in a library) Command
>   /Applications/Xcode
>   2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool
>   failed with exit code 1

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hi, any success over this issue.. i am also getting something similar but with ljs_static flags "error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -ljs_static
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -ljs_static is not an object file (not allowed in a library)"

Comment: same here? any ideas?